# Windows XP , Python 2.7 and Pygame

Tags: python, windows-xp, pygame, python-2.7

How can I make pygame work with Python 2.7 under Windows XP?
I think I need to compile it, but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: In the event that you have more questions to be answered concerning pygame you might want to also hit the pygames-users mailing list. (http://pygame.org/wiki/info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the pygame-1.9.2pre.win32-py2.7 installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: Your link is very useful, especially as are various compilations with python.

Comment: His builds and Tim Golden's libraries are the two greatest things to happen to windows python since the pywin extensions.