# Pygame Installation

Tags: python, installation, pygame, failed-installation

I have python 2.7.1 installed and I'm trying to install pygame (2.6) but when I try compiling a python program I get the following error:

`ImportError: No module named pygame`

Is there a way to fix this without having to install python 2.6

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587018/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides installing python 2.6, you have the option of installing another copy of `pygame` compiled to run with python 2.7.

Since [there isn't one available at pygame website](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) today, I think you'd have to [compile it yourself](http://pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows), using the C source code and a C compiler. (Microsoft Visual Studio or MingW)

Short of compiling, you could use one of [these binaries](http://www3.telus.net/len_l/pygame/) I just digged up from google. They seem to be experimental alpha-quality versions, so don't blame anyone but yourself if things break.

Comment: I had used those bineries and they are fine. I don't know why the pygame folks don't provide a pygame windows installer  for python 2.7 - probably no source change is needed from the the which works with Python 2.6

Comment: So I installed python 2.6.6 for windows 64 and I installed pygame 2.6 but I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to add anything to the system variable path for pygame?  **Edit: Just realized I have to install the 32 bit python  to work with the 32 bit pygame.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I figured out that I wasn't supposed to install python or pygame in the program files directory.

Answer (score 1):

You installed python 2.7 and pygame 2.6. There's a problem. In the pygame website it says to specifically choose the version that is the same as your python version. If you install 2.6 pygame, python 2.7 ignores it because it is for 2.6, but 2.7 is running python 2.7, not 2.6. use this link to install pygame 2.7:
http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi
http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi
Also, if you need pygame, install python 32-bit, not 64-bit. There is no pygame 64-bit. Unfortunate...

Comment: "There is no pygame 64-bit", actually there is: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: yes, but I wanted to use .msi or .exe, because
.whl is just confusing

Comment: It may be confusing, but it still works. At least for my 64 bit computer it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download pygame module which can be done easily by:

```
pip install pygame
```

This worked for me while I was facing issues with the websites instructions.